# Where is the notification push code on Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

Sorry for asking this question. I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to find out the location of the responsible script of sending the notification on submite button event.

When I go to

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/push-notificaiton

You know there you fill the title and message then you submit it to a script or code where you find the targeted auth username.

I want to know the location of that code to edit it in order to do one more things such as inserting title and message in database after sending the push notification to use.

Comment: Please share more details. Either you have written such code on your own, or it is part of Laravel's core functionalities and you should not edit it

Comment: I wrote a code and I want to add it to the push code of laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For laravel 4.2
Go to `app/routes.php`. Search for 'push-notificaiton'. You will find a controller and function next to the url. Go to the controller and find the function

For laravel 5 - 5.2

```
app/Http/routes.php
```

From version 5.3 - 8

```
routes/web.php
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes/web.php` file, you should find a route for that URL. You'll also find the name of a controller next to it. Open up that controller and you'll see the code for the route.